# Raiseerror and Concat for the Message

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, raiseerror

I'd like to do something like this

> ```
> raiserror(concat('Error in case @isFishy =', @isFishy, ' @isSmarmy=', @isSmarmy, ' @isTasty = ', @isTasty), 10, 1)
> --or
> raiserror('Error in case @isFishy =' + @isFishy + ' @isSmarmy=' + @isSmarmy + ' @isTasty = ' + @isTasty, 10, 1)
> ```

But it just isn't working.  How do I accomplish this?  I'm in SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error message in RAISERROR has actually similar syntax to printf function in C, so assuming your arguments are of the type of integer you would need to use:

```
raiserror(N'Error in case @isFishy = %d @isSmarmy = %d @isTasty = %d',10,1,@isFishy,@isSmarmy,@isTasty)
```

check out [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592(SQL.90).aspx) for details and other options

Comment: I realise that your arguments look more like BIT data type rather then INT but it seems that BIT is not supported as a valid type for building the message string

Answer (score 0):

I use raiserror a lot.  We have some stored procedures that are called from a .Net app each night for batch processing, and the .Net app wants to log the procedure output this way.  I don't know why, but I generally have to build the string before calling raiserror.